# Vertical distance of the point from the base of the triangle

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> A triangular figure of height $h$ is given. A point is randomly selected from the triangle. We denote by $X$ to be the vertical distance of the point from the base of the triangle. Find the PDF and the CDF of $X$.

What I thought to do: Let us assume that the base of the triangle is on the horizontal axis. Then we can figure that given $X=x$, it distributes from $0$ to $h$. Since the point is being selected randomly we can conclude that $X\sim Uni(0,h)$ so $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{h}$.

But my professor told me that it is not right and that the solution is to split the triangle to upper triangle and bottom trapeze and then to get:
$$
f_X(x)=\frac{2(h-x)}{h^2}
$$
where $0\leq x\leq h$. Is it possible to explain how did they got it and why my solution isn't valid?

Comment: Your solution isn't valid because the height of a random point in the triangle is not uniformly distributed relative to $h$. That would be the answer for a rectangle. Geometrically, "more" points are nearer the base than the apex. You have to pick the point in the triangle first, then see how far above the base it is.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the length of the base of the triangle is $b$ and you draw a line parallel to the base at height $x$ above the base. Let the length of this line be $y$.

Then by similar triangles, $$\frac{h-x}{y}=\frac{h}{b}\implies y=\frac{b}{h}(h-x)$$

Now consider an infinitesimally thin element of length $y$ and height $\delta x$, whose area is approximately $y\delta x$.

The probability of a point being in this strip is in proportion to the area of the strip, so $$p(X=x)\simeq k\cdot\frac{b}{h}(h-x)\delta x$$

The total probability is $1$, so

$$1=\int_0^hk\cdot\frac{b}{h}(h-x)dx=\frac{kb}{h}\cdot\frac12h^2$$
$$\implies k=\frac{2}{bh}$$

Hence $$f_X(x)=\frac{2(h-x)}{h^2}$$